# Unable to integrate three separate macros into one so that they can be triggered using a single button

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I've created three individual macros to scrape the content of h1 tag from three different sites. The macros are doing fine.

I would like to integrate the three separate macros into one so that when I can execute a single macro, all the three macros will run and write the content in `sheet1`.

The three separate macros are like:

```
Sub FetchInfoOne()
    Const Url$ = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Bacon"
    Dim Html As New HTMLDocument, elem As Object, ws As Worksheet, R&
    
    R = 1
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "Get", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Set elem = Html.querySelector("h1#firstHeading")
    If Not elem Is Nothing Then
        ws.Cells(R, 1) = elem.innerText
    End If
End Sub

Sub FetchInfoTwo()
    Const Url$ = "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/index.htm"
    Dim Html As New HTMLDocument, elem As Object, ws As Worksheet, R&
    
    R = 1
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "Get", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Set elem = Html.querySelector(".tutorial-content > h1")
    If Not elem Is Nothing Then
        ws.Cells(R, 1) = elem.innerText
    End If
End Sub

Sub FetchInfoThree()
    Const Url$ = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"
    Dim Html As New HTMLDocument, elem As Object, ws As Worksheet, R&
    
    R = 1
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "Get", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Set elem = Html.querySelector("h1.fs-headline1")
    If Not elem Is Nothing Then
        ws.Cells(R, 1) = elem.innerText
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If they are all successfull will they overwrite the results? So you are only left with the final set?

Comment: You can consecutively call each of them, but modifying the line `ws.cells(R, 1) = elem.innerText` in the second and third macros, as `(R, 2)` and` (R, 3)`.

Answer (score 3):

Your three routines do nearly the same, so it's a good idea to create one routine and pass parameters with the details

```
Sub FetchInfo(url as string, querySelector as String, destCell as Range)
    Dim Html As New HTMLDocument, elem As Object, ws As Worksheet, R&

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "Get", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Set elem = Html.querySelector(querySelector)
    If Not elem Is Nothing Then
        destCell = elem.innerText
    End If
End Sub
```

Now you create a routine that you call via Button:

```
Sub FetchAll()
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    set ws = ThisWorkbook.sheets("Sheet1")
    
    FetchInfo  "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Bacon", "h1#firstHeading", ws.Cells(1, 1)
    FetchInfo  "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/index.htm", ".tutorial-content > h1", ws.Cells(2, 1)
    FetchInfo  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping", "h1.fs-headline1", ws.Cells(3, 1)
End Sub
```

Benefits: a) Less code. b) More flexible - it's easy to add another URL or write it to a different place in your sheet. c) You separate the logic of fetching the data and the logic to write it to you sheet.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is probably create another Sub and [CALL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/call-statement) the procedures

```
Sub Caller
Call FetchInfoOne
Call FetchInfoTwo
Call FetchInfoThree
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that as well but how that help me loop through the three urls if I wish to put the three urls within `caller` subroutine.

Comment: So have another routine that asks for the 3 urls or just a list...

Answer (score 0):

I would integrate and use the macro in the following manner:

```
Sub Run()
    Dim Http As Object, linkList As Variant, Url As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet, R&
    
    R = 1
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    linkList = Array( _
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Bacon", _
        "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/index.htm", _
        "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping" _
    )
    
    For Each Url In linkList
        If InStr(Url, "en.wikipedia.org") > 0 Then
            FetchInfoOne Http, Url, ws, R
        ElseIf InStr(Url, "www.tutorialspoint.com") > 0 Then
            FetchInfoTwo Http, Url, ws, R
        ElseIf InStr(Url, "stackoverflow.com") > 0 Then
            FetchInfoThree Http, Url, ws, R
        End If
        R = R + 1
    Next Url
End Sub

Sub FetchInfoOne(Http As Object, Url As Variant, ws As Worksheet, R)
    Dim Html As New HTMLDocument, elem As Object

    With Http
        .Open "Get", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Set elem = Html.querySelector("h1#firstHeading")
    If Not elem Is Nothing Then
        ws.Cells(R, 1) = elem.innerText
    End If
End Sub

Sub FetchInfoTwo(Http As Object, Url As Variant, ws As Worksheet, R)
    Dim Html As New HTMLDocument, elem As Object

    With Http
        .Open "Get", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Set elem = Html.querySelector(".tutorial-content > h1")
    If Not elem Is Nothing Then
        ws.Cells(R, 1) = elem.innerText
    End If
End Sub

Sub FetchInfoThree(Http As Object, Url As Variant, ws As Worksheet, R)
    Dim Html As New HTMLDocument, elem As Object

    With Http
        .Open "Get", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Set elem = Html.querySelector("h1.fs-headline1")
    If Not elem Is Nothing Then
        ws.Cells(R, 1) = elem.innerText
    End If
End Sub
```